# Is there any problem with putting alot of widget inside a widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-textinputfield

```
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderDecoratedBox#a8c37 relayoutBoundary=up5
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=350.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  decoration: BoxDecoration
...    border: Border.all(BorderSide)
...    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
...  configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#5fc87(), devicePixelRatio: 1.8, locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
RenderObject: RenderDecoratedBox#a8c37 relayoutBoundary=up5
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=350.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  decoration: BoxDecoration
    border: Border.all(BorderSide)
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
  configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#5fc87(), devicePixelRatio: 1.8, locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
...  child: RenderPadding#a839a relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: <none> (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=350.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: MISSING
...    padding: EdgeInsets(16.0, 21.0, 1.0, 21.0)
...    textDirection: ltr
...    child: RenderFlex#2db32 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: offset=Offset(16.0, 21.0) (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=333.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      size: MISSING
...      direction: vertical
...      mainAxisAlignment: start
...      mainAxisSize: max
...      crossAxisAlignment: start
...      textDirection: ltr
...      verticalDirection: down
...      child 1: RenderParagraph#bb659 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=333.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: Size(66.0, 27.0)
...        textAlign: start
...        textDirection: ltr
...        softWrap: wrapping at box width
...        overflow: clip
...        textScaleFactor: 1.2
...        locale: en_US
...        maxLines: unlimited
...        text: TextSpan
...          debugLabel: ((englishLike bodyMedium 2014).merge(blackMountainView bodyMedium)).merge(unknown)
...          inherit: false
...          color: Color(0xdd000000)
...          family: Roboto
...          size: 20.0
...          weight: 400
...          baseline: alphabetic
...          decoration: TextDecoration.none
...          "Tafuta"
...      child 2: RenderFlex#e8632 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=333.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: MISSING
...        direction: horizontal
...        mainAxisAlignment: start
...        mainAxisSize: max
...        crossAxisAlignment: center
...        textDirection: ltr
...        verticalDirection: down
...        child 1: RenderMouseRegion#2c134 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
...          size: MISSING
...          behavior: opaque
...          listeners: enter, exit
...          cursor: SystemMouseCursor(text)
...        child 2: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#b41ae NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...          parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
...          constraints: MISSING
...          size: MISSING
```

i try hot reload but nothing happened